# store pivot table into csv - preserve all data

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pivot-table

While trying to store the result of [pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) to csv, it doesn't preserve all the data (headers)

Here's the sample code :

```
data = [{'TestPriority': 3, 'AutomationStatus': 'Done'}, 
{'TestPriority': 4, 'AutomationStatus': 'Review'}, {'TestPriority': 2, 
'AutomationStatus': 'Review for Automation'}, {'TestPriority': 2, 
'AutomationStatus': 'Review for Automation'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['AutomationStatus'] = np.where(
    df['AutomationStatus'] == 'Done', 'Automated', 'Manual')
res = df.pivot_table(
    index='AutomationStatus', columns=['TestPriority'],
    aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)
print(res)


res.to_csv('sample.csv', sep=',')
```

the result of print statement is like:

```
TestPriority      2  3  4
AutomationStatus         
Automated         0  1  0
Manual            2  0  1
```

while generated csv does not show `TestPriority` header:

```
AutomationStatus,2,3,4
Automated,0,1,0
Manual,2,0,1
```

Any suggestions on how to properly store the result of pivot_table to csv without loosing data?

Comment: Using to excel , csv will not carry over the format

Comment: could you elaborate a bit more?


this didn't preserve data as well:

```writer = ExcelWriter('sample.xlsx')

res.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')

writer.save()```